# How to add route that does not depend on network reachability?

Tags: networking, route, iproute

I have a pptp server on Centos with Mikrotik routers connecting to it as clients, and I need to add routes between them to enable LAN-to-LAN communication.

I have /etc/ppp/ip-up.local script like this:

```
MYAD=`echo $5| awk -F"." '{print $4}'`
/usr/sbin/route add -net 192.168.$MYAD.0/24 gw 10.42.0.$MYAD
```

So basically, a router which has 192.168.10.0/24 internal network will get 10.42.0.10 ip from pptp and everything works perfectly fine (all routers have unique internal network range)

Except sometimes for some reason the route isn't created. I've added some logging to script, and it is always executed without error and with correct parameters, but the route is not there.

What I would love to do instead, is have something like in Windows, or Mikrotik, or Cisco - add permanent route, so it stays in routing system forever. If 10.42.0.10 is not reachable I am totally fine with blackholing the packets for 192.168.10.0/24

However, Linux would not allow me to create such routes en masse - if 10.42.0.10 is not up, it says "Network is unreachable", and same for any other network. All online manuals on adding persistent routes imply that there are no unreachable networks in my routes. So the question is, how can I create a bunch of routes, even to unreachable networks, and make it stay in routing table forever, until I remove it manually?

P.S. I am in process of moving everything to l2tp ipsec, and there will be a Mikrotik instead of current server, but at the time I need to solve this problem with routes in Linux server

Comment: Did you try to add the same route by hand after inteface is up? Also, a hint: for a point to point interfaces you can add routes via interface: `ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 via ppp10`.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Yes, I can add route manually. It just sometimes fails in script, for unknown reason, and I might just add some error checking to script and try to add it multiple times. But I was hoping for some more straightforward solution instead of hacking around with scripts

Comment: It might fail, for instance, because the script runs too early when the IP addresses aren't still assigned to an interface. The way I suggested to route should not be bothered with this problem, because it doesn't need an interface to have address to add the route.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks for suggestion, I think you were right. I've added 5s delay and it never fails to add a route anymore. The question remains why is ip-up.local executed before the network interface is really up and running, but that is out of scope here.